# Android Emulator - TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to get Traffic Statistics in my Code. But when I use

```
TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid)
```

It always return -1 which is

> TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED

I am not sure how to add support for this in emulator.

Please share your thoughts.

-Vinay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can do this in the emulator. Be aware that there are also devices which don't support this operation. So you have to think of a method to handle this anyway.